# why do I have multiplevertex normals per vertex

Tags: normals

So, in model A I have vertex normals (in magenta) like follows:

[image]

As far as I understand - this is how normals should be - one normal per vertex, storing three coordinates which I can access through object.data.vertices[i].normal

Now, in the model B I have:

[image]

which is obviously like four normals per vertex. Why? I think if I export to a game engine, something bad is bound to happen or? please, see the blender file attached

[image]

Comment: Could you share the second model using blend-exchange?

Comment: First mesh has smooth shading, the second one doesn't. That's what it does - averages normals orientation and that's why it is advised to set both objects to smooth shading when baking normal maps. There was related answer with a graph for normals orientation, can't find it now. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63871/how-to-set-averaged-normals-in-blender

Comment: @MrZak that is interesting thank you. Please feel free to post a short answer